# Google Group 'Set Posting Permissions' and 'Change Delivery Settings'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am trying to change 'posting permissions' and 'delivery settings' for specific users in specific groups using some sort of API so things can be automated.  When I log in to Google admin I have the following actions to apply to users:

http://postimg.org/image/5yq1pis3b/

I've been looking for a bit and have only been able to find the ability to change a user's role in a group.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/update

Does anyone know if what I am trying to do is supported by Google in some API?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only user specific settings for Google Groups for Business are the user role, and that is limited to only the three baked-in roles of member, manager, and owner. 
Other than that, only group wide settings are supported, and what is supported in the API and what is supported in the web console are not an exact match.

Hopefully, this will change as the API matures.